# Is the Joker based on anything?

Tags: dc, inspiration, the-joker

Is the Joker based on another character, or a real life person?

[image: montage of multiple pictures of the Joker, from cartoons/film/etc]

Comment: I'm strongly resisting the urge to be an evil clown and post a link to the tvtropes page for "Monster Clown" and burn your day (and possibly weekend). :)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.themarysue.com/the-man-who-laughs-the-movie-that-inspired-batmans-joker-sort-of-turns-86/), Batman creators Bob Kane and Bill Finger created the Joker based on a combination of the playing card (obviously) and the character played by Conrad Veidt in the 1928 silent movie [*The Man Who Laughs*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Man_Who_Laughs_(1928_film)), who looked like this:

[image]

And in the middle picture here, side by side with the card and the Batman villain:

[image]

Compare with the earliest Joker design in the comics:

[image]

The article quotes Bob Kane saying:

> Bill Finger and I created the Joker. Bill was the writer. Jerry Robinson came to me with a playing card of the Joker. That’s the way I sum it up. But he looks like Conrad Veidt – you know, the actor in The Man Who Laughs… So Bill Finger had a book with a photograph of Conrad Veidt and showed it to me and said, “Here’s the Joker.”

And here's the description of the character in *The Man Who Laughs*, who always had a smile on his face because he'd been disfigured as a child:

> Based on Victor Hugo’s novel L’Homme Qui Rit, The Man Who Laughs tells the tale of Gwynplaine, a man who had a permanent smile carved into his face as a child as punishment for having a rebel-rousing nobleman for a father. Deformed, he now works in a traveling circus and is in a relationship with a blind woman named Dea. Matters get complicated when the femme fatale Duchess Josiana takes a perverse fancy to him and the Queen learns of Gwynplaine’s noble lineage.

Comment: So *that's* how he got those scars!